# How can I find any different objects between two pictures in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

After reading two images (a,b), I want to find any object in "b" image that does not exists in the first image "a" and object could be of any shape does not matter, the two images are pictures captured in the same place with the same state of the camera. But could be some differences, I want to have the number of these different objects.

this what have tried so far

```
i = imread('camera1.jpg');
j = imread('camera4.jpg');
 a = im2double(i)
b = im2double(j)

f1= ones(3,3)/9;
i1=imfilter(i,a);
j1=imfilter(j,b);


ed1 = edge(i1);
ed2 = edge(j1);

madBlock = mean2(abs(double(ed1) - double(ed2)))
```

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: i = imread('camera1.jpg');
j = imread('camera4.jpg');
 

a= im2double(i)
b= im2double(j)

f1= ones(3,3)/9;
a1=imfilter(i,a);
bi=imfilter(j,b);

madBlock = mean2(abs(double(a1) - double(b1)))

Comment: Update your post to have this code.  It looks terrible in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the simplest way is to align these two images (e.g. in Hugin) and calculate difference `diff = |b-a|`. 
Next step is thresholding: set to zero all pixels in `diff` that lower than a threshold. After that do median filtering to omit salt/pepper noice and apply connected components search (marching squares method). You will find differences between images.